# When do I know that my project has been really built?

Tags: xpages

Following Martin Jinoch's stern admonition to turn 'automatically build' off, I'm doing it the manual way but have some questions:

- Is there any way to visually determine when the project is built and I can test it?
- I'm missing some sort of keyboard shortcut to build my current Project (CTRL-B for all takes too much time)
- Sometimes when I make changes the 'Build Project' menu line is greyed out, and I clean it instead. Am I missing something?

Comment: Regarding CTRL-B: that's also a reason why I use working sets and have only the app opened in the navigator that I am working on, so CTRL-B (build all) alsways just builds the current app. You can determine if the build is still running by checking the progressbar in the status area or open the progress view in a separate tab.

Comment: For me it's a combination of remapping CTRL+B to Build Project (as Knut points out) and monitoring the Progress view when I fire off a build (as Oliver points out).

Comment: I find the way that Builds are done without providing any obvious notice to be one of the more frustrating things about the current Designer client. I think that assumed only odd people would turn off Build Automatically, so never worried about providing any visual indicators.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change the CTRL+B key from "Build All" to "Build Project".

Open Preferences General/Keys, search for "Build" and remove CTRL+B for "Build All" and set it for "Build Project":

[image]

Comment: CTRL+F8 is another useful shortcut in Designer: it toggles between Domino Designer Perspective and Debug Perspective.

Comment: In fact, it cycles through last used perspectives. DD and Debug are in YOUR perspective history ;-)

Comment: Haha, @Frantisek you're right, I have had only those both perspectives open yet. After opening a third perspective you get a popup window pressing CTRL+F8. But, thankfully, still toggles between last two perspectives :-) Whew!

Answer (score 3):

The Designer taskbar will show first: "Building...", then "Done". Unfortunately the "Progress" view is not updated.

If the "Build" option is greyed out, it can be launched when you switch to either "Navigator" or "Project Explorer" view.